# Configuring Python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, pycharm, apache-flink, fedora, pyflink

I am trying to configure Python Virtual Environment by following the steps [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/python/installation/) and using the script from [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/downloads/setup-pyflink-virtual-env.sh) on my Fedora laptop and later using it in PyCharm. When execute the script is returning the following error:

```
Collecting fasteners<1.0,>=0.3 (from apache-beam==2.43.0->apache-flink)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a2/7d35ba2c8d9963398fcec49cd814e50a6b920d213928f06fdbbf8aa3289b/fasteners-0.18-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio!=1.48.0,<2,>=1.33.1 (from apache-beam==2.43.0->apache-flink)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/13/f7e3834ba272c0058c66de57272fb3b20dde69003032fdb6b4d7c36eebed/grpcio-1.53.0.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sctv696j/grpcio/setup.py", line 262, in <module>
        if check_linker_need_libatomic():
      File "/tmp/pip-install-sctv696j/grpcio/setup.py", line 212, in check_linker_need_libatomic
        stderr=PIPE)
      File "/home/monika.hristova/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/home/monika.hristova/Documents/venv/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c++': 'c++'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-sctv696j/grpcio/
```

[image]
Can someone help me with what I need to do?

Comment: post your error as a text, so it is searchable and easier to read.

Comment: Hello, can you expose the commands to you are using the set it up you virtual env.?, in that way will be easier to replicate your problem.

Comment: @FrancoGil the commands are in the script attached to the post. - https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/downloads/setup-pyflink-virtual-env.sh

Comment: @MonikaX You don't have C++ compiler installed. See suggestions in the thread https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24556

Comment: Try installing the grcpio separately